# Геолокация в HTML5

Tags: html, html5

Какие могут быть практические применения геолокации в HTML5? 
Попадались ли вам сайты (или, может, вы их сами делали) с интересным/красивым/практичным применением геолокации? (желательно со ссылками на эти сайты)

Comment: А что вы конкретно имеете ввиду?

Comment: @miss_julie можно найти примеры использования геолокации, например здесь, http://html5demos.com/geo , а мне интересно, есть ли уже на каких-то сайтах использование геолокации с какими-либо практическими целями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть много вариантов, когда геолокация очень нужна

- сайты с погодой (meteoprog & gismeteo мне постоянно показывает Киев, хотя я не там нахожусь - вот им нужно было бы ее использовать)
- сайты интернет магазинов. Зачем спрашивать, где живет пользователь, если это можно узнать?
- различные социальные сети - что бы показать, кто из друзей находится рядом.
- поисковики. Что бы показывать более актуальную информацию. Но им хватает определения по ip на уровне города/страны.
- рекламные сети, что бы показывать целевую рекламу.

По моему опыту в основном геолокацией пользуются мобильные сайты (в том числе гугл) - там по ip бывает сложно определить положение пользователя.